# Converting Yii2 responses to Json responses for mobile apps

Tags: web-services, rest, yii2

I have a Yii2 App and we want to start building restful services for the mobile devices.

I have the URL's as

```
"users/photos"
"users/videos"
"users/profile"
```

They all render Html response. What I would like to do is to pass another parameter in the URL and convert the response into JSON and send all the view variables as JSON output. So, I don't have worry about code duplication.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If your result is an array you can do it like this:

```
public function actionPhotos($json = false)
{
    if ($json) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    }

    // the rest stays the same
}
```

If this is just some rendered HTML view you have to prepare separate action (or add conditional return).

Comment: This would be too much of work. I can't go to each and every method and add an additional argument - that would be timing consuming. I took a better approach by creating a new controller class and extending it to "yii\web\Controller" and then overwriting the render function. I was able achieve pretty much of what I needed but I am still not sure how to handle $this->rediect(). If I overwrite the function I don't get the $this->render() view variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can set response data format wherever you want to change the returned data format by using this in you method or even a condition occurs:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

Also you can use other data response formats available in Yii2 from [This API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#constants)

You may also change the response format whithin a certain condition.
For example change the response format to JSON when the request to the controller is Ajax

Answer (score 0):

you can change behaviors for doing that 
as an example like it

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're actions are returning.

**1.** For simple cases like either rendering a HTML view or returning an array of data when requesting json output, I'd go with [@Bizley suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767499/converting-yii2-responses-to-json-responses-for-mobile-apps#answer-40769002). that is the easiest and the best for most of those cases.

**2.** If you are planning to support and maintain many output formats and not only json then a different option is to implement the built-in [yii\filters\ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html) where you'll be able to override `\yii\web\Response` by your own designed classes in a future if required:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'contentNegotiator' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                'application/javascript' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSONP,
                'application/xml' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML,
                'text/plain' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW,
                'text/html' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_HTML,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionAbout()
{
    switch (\Yii::$app->response->format) {
        case 'json':
        case 'xml':
            return ['a'=>'b'];
            break;

        default:
            return $this->render('about');
            break;
    }
}
```

This should work by setting the `_format` url attribute to the desired output like:

```
http://localhost/some_app/web/index.php?r=site/about&_format=json
```

**3.** For advanced cases where model instances should be returned and serialized, pagination is to be supported (like `GET /data?per-page=5&page=2`), pagination related links and meta are expected in headers, model validation errors should be fetched,... In that case I'd recommend using or creating a similar Controller class to the [yii/rest/controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-controller.html) which is built as a child of the [yii/web/controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html) class and using the built-in [yii/rest/serializer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-serializer.html) class when outputting data. Its full source code isn't hard to follow and can be found [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/Controller.php).

**4.** If what you need is a full REST implementation by supporting all verbs, status codes, actions for CRUD, etag caching... then I'd recommand implementing the built-in RESTful Web Service API which documentaion starts here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html.